# C# JsonResult with JObject element returns empty array

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return a JSON result from a REST API that includes a JsonObject as an element.

```
var aJsonObject = new JObject();
aJsonObject.Add("somefield", "somevalue" );
aJsonObject.Add("someotherfield", 1995);

return Json( new { status = "success", result = aJsonObject } );
```

The client receives an empty nested arrays:

`{"status":"success","result":[[[]],[[]]]}`

My work around, which I don't love, is to serialize the JsonObject, thus sending it as a string and then having the client parse it.  It works, but it's a bit ugly.

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

NOTE: 8/3/18 I edited the variable declaration to correct a typo - it was jsonObject and should have been aJsonObject

Comment: Your example you gave, and your result, don't match up at all.

Comment: Why do you want to return a JObject rather then an object?

Comment: Why are you declaring `jsonObject` but populating and returning `aJsonObject`? Are you simply mixing up your variables?

Comment: @ozum.e  I need it to be dynamic - I won't know the fields I am adding to the object until run time so I cannot declare a class to make an POCO from.

Comment: @DanWilson  Sorry - that was typo... I renamed objects and variables for the purpose of posting the question to avoid publishing real code.  I corrected the post and made a note that I edited it.

Comment: @FrankerZ I agree that it doesn't look like it would, but that's what I got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JObject is already json-formatted. Main purpose of JsonResult is to serialize an object to json. What you are trying to do is (I guess):

```
dynamic resultObject = new ExpandoObject();
resultObject.somefield = "somevalue";
resultObject.someotherfield = 1995;

return Json( new { status = "success", result = resultObject } );
```

If you want to build the Json string yourself and return it to the client you can use Content:

```
return new Content(yourjsonstring, "application/json");
```

Comment: In my case, the object to serialize to Json, contains a property that has a type of JObject. When this happens, return Json(myObject) will blank out that property's json value and return the empty array like Daniel C showed in his original post - where it should just pass it on in my opinion. The other non-json properties serialize just fine. Feels like a bug to me.

Comment: Ig1382, how did you solve what you describe?  I'm having the same issue...help!

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to keep using JObject, this works (and then return the JSON as @ozum.e describes):

```
var jObject = new JObject();
jObject.Add("someField", "someValue");
jObject.Add("otherField", 1995);
var newObj = new { status = "success", result = jObject };
var returnThis = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObj);
```